# mkdir vs New-Item , is it the same cmdlets?

Tags: powershell

I found that there are two different cmdlets : `New-Item` and `mkdir`, firstly I was thinking that `mkdir` is one of aliases of `New-Item`, but it is not: [image]

Try to get aliases of it, it is `md` for `mkdir` and `ni` for `New-Item` :[image]

So I am a little bit confused, what the difference between that cmdlets, because powershell reference gives me almost the same pages: [`mkdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/mkdir?view=powershell-6), [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6) 
But `New-Item` is in `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` and `mkdir` in `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core` , but the do the same(or not?)! Why there are two same cmdlets in powershell?

Comment: To see the definition of mkdir, use `Get-Content Function:\mkdir`

Comment: @RyanBemrose   `<#
.FORWARDHELPTARGETNAME New-Item
.FORWARDHELPCATEGORY Cmdlet
#> ` - does it means, that it is absolutely the same? If yes, why mkdir is not alias of `New-Item` ? Why Microsoft  dublicate code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`New-Item` is a cmdlet, defined in an assembly, which creates new objects - both files and directories.  `mkdir` is a function which calls `New-Item` to create directories specifically.  It is provided for convenience to shell users who are familiar with Windows CMD or unix shell command `mkdir`

To see the definition of `mkdir` use `Get-Content Function:\mkdir`.  You can see that it calls `New-Item` under the covers, after some parameter and pipeline management.  Using PS 5.0:

```
$wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('New-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
$scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd -Type Directory @PSBoundParameters }
```

Both of the following commands will create a new directory named `foo` in the root of `C:\`.  The second form is familiar to people coming from other shells (and shorter to type).  The first form is idiomatic PowerShell.

```
PS> New-Item -Path C:\foo -Type Directory
PS> mkdir C:\foo
```

Because `mkdir` hardcodes the `-Type Directory` parameter, it can only be used to create directories.  There is no equivalent `mkfile` built-in function. To create files, use `New-Item -Type File`, or another cmdlet such as `Out-File`.

Comment: thanks, that means I can't create files with `mkdir`

Comment: Alternative to `Get-Content Function:\mkdir` and faster to type imho: `gcm mkdir | fl`

Comment: Weird, but "Get-Content Function:\mkdir" returns an error, but the shortcut that @Clijsters posted works. I'm using PowerShell 7.3.4 on Linux.  Could be a difference running powershell on Linux vs Windows.  I think because on my RHEL8 system gcm is aliased to Get-Command not Get-Content.

Comment: @shawn1874 yes, exactly. `mkdir` is a function in windows but a binary in linux. That's why I prefer gcm.